# Inject mvn dependency using python

Tags: java, python, maven, dependency-injection

I have some java projects using maven and I should inject the surefire dependency into each of them at run-time. How can I do that?

Comment: For java related question, use the java tag instead of python

Comment: Surefire is a plugin to run unit tests which should never been added as a dependency...and usually a maven project already has maven-surefire-plugin bound to the lifecycle so in the end I don't understand your question?

Comment: because I need to verify the independence of the test cases, so I would need to be able to change their execution at every run and since I have many projects to verify, I would like a way to automamtize